# Hartshorne Chapter IV, Exercise 5.6

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I am struggling to prove the following statements

- A nonsingular plane curve of degree $5$ has no $g^1_3$.
- There are nonhyperelliptic curves of genus $6$ which cannot be represented as a nonsingular plane quintic curve.

I assume the second statement is shown by proving that there exists a nonhyperelliptic curve of genus $6$ with a $g^1_3$, but I do not know how to construct such a curve.

Comment: A non-singular plane curve of degree $d\ge 3$ has gonality $d-1$, and all gonal maps are given by the projection onto a line from a point in the curve. This may help you to show the first result. For the second, just find a trigonal curve of genus 6, like the one given by the singular planar equation $X^7 + X^4Y^3 + Z^7$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think we can handle the second point by a dimension count. The moduli space of genus $g=6$ curves has dimension $3g-3 = 15$.

On the other hand, the space of plane quintics has dimension ${5+2\choose 2} - 1 = 20$. Dividing out by the action of $PGL(3)$, which has dimension $8$, we get a $12$-dimensional space of plane quintics up to isomorphism. So the locus of plane curves has codimension $3$ in the moduli space.

As for the first point, the general idea should be to suppose that a genus $6$ curve simultaneously admits a $g^1_3$ and a $g^2_5$, but I haven't found a contradiction yet.

Answer (score 2):

First, I answer the second part following your suggestion: by using the first part, one only needs to construct a trigonal curve of genus 6. It is well known that there are trigonal curves for every genus $\ge 3$: for example by considering cyclic covers of $\mathbb{P}^1$, i.e. given by an equation of the form
$$y^3= \prod_{i=1}^s (x-\alpha_i)^{r_i},$$
where $r_i=1$ or $2$. If $\sum_{i=1}^s r_i\equiv 0 \pmod{3}$, then the place at infinity does not ramify, and the ramification index at $x=\alpha_i$ is always $e_i=3$. Hurwitz formulae gives then that $g=s-2$. For example, in our case we can take the equation
$$y^3=(x^7+1)(x-1)^2.$$

Now for the first part: suppose we have $X$ a smooth planar curve of degree 5. Then we have that $\omega_X \cong \mathcal{O}_X(2)$, so $H^0(\mathbb{P}^2, \mathcal{O}(2)) \to H^0(X, \omega_X)$ is an isomorphism. So the canonical embedding of $X$ is isomorphic to the composition $X \to \mathbb{P}^2 \stackrel{\phi}{\longrightarrow} \mathbb{P}^{5}$ where $\phi$ is the $2$-fold Veronese, given as
$$\phi([x_0:x_1:x_2])=[x_0^2: x_0x_1: x_1^2: x_0x_2: x_1x_2: x_2^2].$$

Now, suppose we have $\psi: X\to \mathbb{P}^1$ be a degree 3 morphism, and consider a "general" fiber $(p_1,p_2,p_3)$ (so $\psi(p_i)=\psi(p_j) \forall i,j$). Denote by $D=p_1+p_2+p_3$ the effective divisor; we have then that $\dim |D|=1$, so by Riemann-Roch, $\dim |K-D|=3$ ($K$ denotes a canonical divisor). Since $\phi(X)$ is canonical, this means that the the dimension of the linear system of hyperplanes in $\mathbb{P}^5$ that contains $\phi(p_1)$, $\phi(p_2)$ and $\phi(p_3)$ is 3, so the three points are colinear (compare with Hartshorne, Chapter IV, Example 5.5.3).

But for a "generic" fiber this is not possible: we can choose one such that $p_i=[1:p_{i 1}: p_{i 2}]$ and such that $p_{i 1}\ne 0$ for all $i=1,2,3$ and distinct. But then
$$\phi(p_i)=[1:p_{i 1}:p_{i 1}^2:\cdots]$$
and this points are clearly not colinear (by "Vadermonde").

Comment: I do not understand how you go from $y^3 = \prod (x-\alpha)^r$ to the curve you specified.

Comment: The curve specified is the case we have s=8 (so 8 roots), and $r_1=\dots=r_7=1$ and $r_8=2$.

Comment: Pardon the late comment, but can you explain a bit about why $\sum r_i=0\pmod 3$ implies no ramification over $\infty$?

Comment: @hank-scorpio I think your question should be asked separately, as the answer I know is not short.

Comment: @xarles Ok, I've followed your advice and asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4352258/ramification-at-infinity-for-a-cyclic-cover-of-bbb-p1).

Answer (score 0):

*A sketch*: You can find a nonsingular curve $X$ of genus $6$ and degree $7$ in $\mathbb{P}^3$, e.g., a curve of type $(3,4)$ on the Segre surface $\mathbb{P}^1\times \mathbb{P}^1$. The very ample divisor $H$ of $X\subset\mathbb{P}^3$ is a $g_7^3$, and by Riemann-Roch theorem you can easily see that $K-H$ is a $g_3^1$, where $K$ is the canonical divisor of $X$. This shows that $X$ cannot be represented by a nonsingular plane quintic curve.