# Ramification at infinity for a cyclic cover of $\Bbb P^1$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4098106/), xarles constructs a cyclic cover of $\Bbb P^1$ as the field extension $k(x)\subset k(x,y)$, where $y^3=\prod_{i=1}^s (x-\alpha_i)^{r_i}$ and claims that if $\sum_{i=1}^s r_i=0\pmod 3$, then the place at infinity does not ramify. I do not understand how to see this, and I'd like some help with the argument.

I roughly understand how to do this in the case that the exponent of $y$ is 2: you have a double cover of $\Bbb P^1$, so the ramification index at any point is at most 2, but the sum of the ramification indexes minus 1 must be even by Riemann-Hurwitz. So if you can verify that you have an even sum of (ramification indexes minus 1) over the finite places, then you can conclude that there can't be any ramification at infinity. Problem is, now that we're moving to $3$ instead of $2$, that argument no longer works because it was based on parity.

Comment: If $char(k)\ne 3$ and $\sum_i r_i = 3d$ then the polynomial $T^3-x^{-3d} \prod_i (x-\alpha_i)^{r_i}\in \overline{k}[x^{-1}][T]$ splits completely in $\overline{k}[[x^{-1}]]$, which gives your 3 embeddings $k(x,y)\to k((x^{-1}))$ and your 3 unramified places above $x=\infty$.

Comment: The point at infinity added to your affine curve $C:y^3=\prod_i (x-\alpha_i)^{r_i}$ is ramified in the map $C\to \Bbb{P}^1$ but when considering the places of the field extension we are considering the smooth projective curve underlying $C$ where the point at infinity becomes 3 distinct points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\sum r_i = 3d$ one can construct the cyclic covering of $\mathbb{P}^1$ as
$$
C = \mathrm{Spec}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(\mathcal{O} \oplus \mathcal{O}(-d) \oplus \mathcal{O}(-2d)),
$$
where the algebra struture is induced by the morphism
$$
\mathcal{O}(-3d) \to \mathcal{O}
$$
that has zero of multiplicity $r_i$ at point $\alpha_i$. The induced field extension is exactly the same and by construction there is no ramification at infinity.

Comment: Why no ramification at infinity?

Comment: Because the morphism $\mathcal{O}(-3d) \to \mathcal{O}$ has no zero at infinity.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a topological reason why $\infty$ is not ramified.

By removing the ramification points over $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_s$, the curve defines a 3-sheeted covering space of $U=\mathbb C-\{\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_s\}$. We pick a base point $\alpha_0\in U$, then any loop $l\subseteq U$ based at $\alpha_0$ defines a permutation action of the three points on the fiber. In other words, we have a representation

$$\rho:\pi_1(U,\alpha_0)\to S_3.$$

We can choose a loop $l_{\infty}$ large enough to enclose all the $\alpha_i$'s and counter-clockwise oriented.

**Claim:** *The infinity point $\infty$ is not ramified if and only if $\rho(l_{\infty})$ is identity element.*

The problem reduces to prove the latter statement. We perturb the equation a little to separate the branching points whenever $\alpha_i$ is not simple. So we can assume the equation is

$$y^3=\Pi_{i=1}^{3n}(x-\beta_i),$$

where $n$ is an integer and all $\beta_i$'s are distinct and contained in $l_{\infty}$. Of course, this doesn't change the topology far away from the branchings.

Now, we can choose $l_i$ is a loop based at $\alpha_0$ and only enclose $\beta_i$ and counter-clockwise oriented. Then up to relabelling the index, $l_{\infty}$ is homotopic to the concatenation $l_{3n}*l_{3n-1}*\cdots*l_1$. See picture [below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxDiim.jpg).

Finally, each $\rho(l_i)$ is the same generator $\sigma:1\mapsto 2\mapsto 3\mapsto 1$ of the cyclic subgroup permutating the three points (this is because topologically along $l_i$, the curve looks like a small circle around zero on $y^3=x$). Therefore $$\rho(l_{\infty})=\rho(l_{3n})\cdot\rho(l_{3n-1})\cdots\rho(l_1)=\sigma^{3n}=e$$
is the identity element.

$\hspace{5cm}$
[image: Concatenation of loops]

Answer (score 0):

Let me add an answer. You can blow up the point at infinity $d$ times(then you get the normalization of $V_+(z^{3d-3}y^3-\prod(x-\alpha_i z)^{r_i})$) in which the (singular) point at infinity splits into 3 points, hence $[0,1,0]$ doesn't ramify.

The calculation is not hard at all and I believe you can handle it in just a few minutes.